# Does uBlock Origin make Ghostery redundant?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions, adblock, noscript, ghostery

I have [uBlock Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm) installed in my browser, as well as AdBlock.

Does having uBlock Origin mean there is no point to running [Ghostery](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ghostery/mlomiejdfkolichcflejclcbmpeaniij)?  Will Ghostery find and suppress any scripts that uBlock Origin does not already detect?

(I am using Google Chrome, but I would also be interested if the answer is any different for Firefox.)

Comment: This is something you personally will have to decide.  We cannot tell you if you need or don't need to use an add-on.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the feedback. My question is whether one makes the other redundant. Am I just wasting overhead by running multiple extensions that do the same thing, or is there some benefit to running two or all three of them?

Comment: uBlock Origin relies 100% on filter lists.

Comment: I use them both, Ghostery has ~100k list of trackers, while uBlock has around 90k of Ads-related filters. I'm sure there are big overlaps but until uBlock has a list of updated trackers of 10000s I will keep using them both.

Answer (score 3):

I am curious of this also for my old underpowered cellphone.   here I am looking at this page with chromebook / chrome browser, both ublock origin and ghostery running. both are geared for maximum defense/blocking of everything possible.

ub has 4 items blocked and ghostery has 5 blocked.

I just tested and reloaded several times turning one off, then the other, both off, then turned them on in opposite order.  Was thinking that one was blocking some elements so the other never saw them to block them but the counts were the same with or without the other defender running.

9 items on this page being blocked by using them simultaneously.  so for what is worth,  I satisfied my curiosity on needing to use them both.  if my little dinosaur can handle them both without heating up or crashing the rooted eclair,  i will run them both.

Comment: About the "items blocked" indicator: if one tracker would then load 100 trackers, it's better to have _all_ of them blocked (will show as 1 blocked) than the first one not blocked (will show as 100 blocked). See [uBlock Origin's developer on the subject](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/About-%22This-other-extension-reports-more-stuff-blocked!%22).

Answer (score 3):

I really, really want uBlock to make Ghostery redundant.  However, I find that Ghostery blocks such services as http://fullstory.com and http://intercom.io .  I have been unable to find a blocking list that includes those.

Comment: Just add the two sites to "My Filters": "One filter per line. A filter can be a **plain hostname**, or an Adblock Plus-compatible filter. Lines prefixed with ‘!’ will be ignored."

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's no point to use Ghostery if you use uBlock with the third-party privacy lists on. They are very comprehensive and more transparent than Ghostery.

Comment: [citation needed]